# How can I edit a pdf file which has already been uploaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

I want to add a footer to a pdf file that is on the server.

example
I uploaded file to uploads/aaa.pdf

and I want add footer in file uploads/aaa.pdf

How I can do it?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? by your self?

Comment: You cannot do it without a hell of a lot of php knowledge.

Comment: Use a PDF class like [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com), fPDF, [tcPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org). There is plenty of information online and examples.

Comment: I do not mean to make a file pdf, the file is uploaded
be modified to add this footer.

Comment: @KwangKung: To do that you need to read the PDF data, modify it and create new PDF (whether it is just the footer or completely new data does not matter)

Comment: is the footer per page? of could you just glue the 'footer' file on to the end of the original to make a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work

```
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf =& new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();

//Set the source PDF file
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile(“Tally_PO.pdf”);

//Import the first page of the file
$tppl = $pdf->importPage(1);

//Use this page as template
// use the imported page and place it at point 20,30 with a width of 170 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tppl, -10, 20, 210);

#Print Hello World at the bottom of the page

//Select Arial italic 8
$pdf->SetFont(‘Arial’,”,8);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetXY(90, 160);

$pdf->Write(0, “Hello World”);

$pdf->Output(“modified_pdf.pdf”, “F”);
```

referent : http://pranavom.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/modify-pdf-using-fpdffpdi-library/